# Can I use sudo -u myuser systemctl on Debian Jessie?

Tags: bash, shell, debian, sudo, systemd

I want to reload `squid3` with a limited user with this command:

```
sudo -u myuser systemctl reload squid3.service
```

the output is:

> Failed to reload squid3.service: Access denied

Sudoers' file is correctly filled and if I log me with myuser:

```
sudo systemctl reload squid3.service
```

it works.

So what I mess or I can't use `systemctl` with `sudo -u myuser` ?

Comment: `sudo -u myuser sudo systemctl reload squid3.service` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find with sudo...

> sudo sh -c '/bin/systemctl reload squid3.service' -u myuser

Answer (score 0):

It will help if you provide `sudo -l` output when you logged in as your regular user and `myuser`. Does `sudo -i -u myuser systemctl ...` work?

Comment: It's not working Failed to restart squid3.service: Access denied

Comment: I guess your solution will work without `sh -c`. Trouble was with PATH variable. In sudo rule you should write absolute paths to executables.